# Can someone tell me why my Java While Loop is not exiting properly?

Tags: java

Alright so my loop is working as intented, however it seems to not exit the loop. I determined this because nothing executes in my main function after the line where I call this function

```
        public static void Simulator(int N){
    double x=0.01;
    int t=0;
    System.out.println(x);
    while(t<=N){
        x=3.5*x*(1-x);
        System.out.println(x);
        t=t+1;
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Comment: There are a couple of things to fix here. This is not a main function. See here http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/main.html. You didn't mention the value of N when you run your program. It helps if you provide the code of your whole main() function.

Comment: @BuiTheHoa I believe he is making a method and that he is calling this method elsewhere. Can the OP confirm my claims?

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled and tested the sample of code that you have given by making a sample program (where `N = 10`, not passed in):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t = 0;
    int N = 10;
    double x = 0.01;

    while (t <= N) {
        x = 3.5 * x * (1 - x);
        System.out.println(x);
        t = t + 1;
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
0.03465
1
0.11707282125
2
0.36178371521097946
3
0.8081369051669213
4
0.5426807668595311
5
0.8686242324909882
6
0.3994066132715046
7 
0.8395833969127198
8
0.4713909078942638
9
0.8721353194710993
10
0.3903035640074999
11
```

From this, it can be concluded that it must be something else in your main method that is causing the problem as the loop executes and exits properly.

Check that you are calling the `Simulator` method properly in your main method.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The loop is working fine. I don't know what you're doing afterwards, but it will enter inside that while exactly N+1 times.

Also, you should consider using a for instead:

```
for(int t=0; t <= N; t++)
{
    x=3.5*x*(1-x);
}
```